# How to catch R background code in rmr map reduce in Rhadoop

Tags: r, hadoop, mapreduce

I am new in R Hadoop. I am able to run map reduce function of rmr package with Hadoop. Basically in background R runs this map reduce code in Java. It means R converts this R map reduce code in Java, So can I get the java background code when running map reduce.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

In Rhadoop, R is not converting R Map Reduce code to java.Rhadoop provides MapReduce interface; mapper and reducer can be described in R code and then called from R.

> Rhadoop package will submit R code to Hadoop Cluster using Hadoop
>   streaming.Hadoop streaming is a utility that comes with the Hadoop
>   distribution. The utility allows you to create and run Map/Reduce jobs
>   with any executable or script as the mapper and/or the reducer.

You can understand about this by going throug Rhadoop package code in [GitHub](https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/rmr2).

The RHadoop package submit the hadoop streaming job by using **System** command in R.
You can get an idea about this from this [R scipt](https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/rmr2/blob/master/pkg/R/streaming.R) in RMR package.The code in that streaming.R is as given below.

```
  final.command =
    paste(
      hadoop.command, 
      stream.mapred.io,  
      if(is.null(backend.parameters)) ""
      else
        do.call(paste.options, backend.parameters), 
      input, 
      output, 
      mapper, 
      combiner,
      reducer, 
      image.cmd.line, 
      m.fl, 
      r.fl, 
      c.fl,
      input.format.opt, 
      output.format.opt, 
      "2>&1")
  if(verbose) {
    retval = system(final.command)
    if (retval != 0) stop("hadoop streaming failed with error code ", retval, "\n")}
  else {
    console.output = tryCatch(system(final.command, intern=TRUE), 
                              warning = function(e) stop(e)) 
    0}}
```